# How to pass variable from render in web.py to def in mako

Tags: python, web.py, mako

I'm trying to pass the follwoing

```
return render('warps.html', query=query)
```

To a mako template and have it read the query with the follwoing.

```
<%def name="warps()">
    <%
    warp = db.warps.find('player' : ${query}).sort(u'player', 1)
    print warp
    %>
    %for x in warp:
        ${x['player']},&nbsp;&nbsp;${x['x_origin']},${x['y_origin']}&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;${x['x_dest']},${x['y_dest']}<br />
    %endfor
</%def>
```

The `${query}` works fine outside of the `<% -- %>` block but within it has to have "" around it. So if I print it i get `${query}` as a string instead of the variable that `${query}` is supposed to represent.

Is there a way to pass a render variable from web.py into the python on a mako template?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be:

```
warp = db.warps.find('player' : query).sort(u'player', 1)
```

BTW, you shouldn't put logic in the template.

Comment: Thanks :-) - lol, I thought that might have been it but I had already gone to bed and was too tired to get back up to try it. 

I'm using logic in the template because at the moment I don't know how to return the results of a For loop from the web.py script. It returns the first result but exits after one. I'm using a form to select the value for the query variable to return just what was selected, not the entire collection of warps. What would be the better way to do that?